# is there a another way to do this or i am missing something

Tags: python

> **Question**
>
> Given two integers a and b, your task is to calculate:
>
> - a+b
> - a- b
> - a*b
> - a//b
>
> **Input**
>
> User Task:
> Since this will be a functional problem, you don't have to take input. You just have to complete the function
> operations() that takes the integer a and b as parameters.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> - 1 <= b <= a <= 1000
>
> Note: It is guaranteed that a will be divisible by b.
>
> **Output**
>
> Print the mentioned operations each in a new line.

This is my code:

```
def operations(X,Y):
  return X+Y

def minus(X,Y):
  return X-Y

def multi(X,Y):
  return X*Y

def div(X,Y):
  return X/Y

X = 15
Y = 3

print(minus(X,Y))
print(operations(X,Y))
print(multi(X,Y))
print(div(X,Y))
```

It would be a huge help if someone tells me if the code I am doing has something wrong with it.

Comment: in div, // is missing

Comment: I think the question wants the + - / * to fall under operations, and don't need to be separate functions?

Comment: i made changes please see again

Comment: @LarrytheLlama what i want is exact output and can we do all arithmetic operators in one function with predefined input

Comment: The question title should describe your problem well enough so that readers get the gist of what it's about. See: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem asks you to add the functions `minus`, `multi` and `div`. You only need to implement the function `operations` and make print the result of the four operation each in one line. Which can be done like this:

```
def operations(a, b):
  print(a + b)
  print(a - b)
  print(a * b)
  print(a // b)
```

Notice how I used a double slash (`//`) for division instead of a single slash (`/`). Because a single slash in python will give you a float value even though `a` and `b` are integers. ie. `4 / 2` will return `2.0` where the problem is clearly asking for integer values (cf. the note), in this case `2`

Answer (score 0):

if you use (/)   11/3 in division then it will return float value (3.666666...) if you use(//)    11//3 it will give you a rounded int value  (3)